# Application of Implicit Differentiation Problems

Tags: calculus, derivatives, problem-solving, implicit-differentiation, word-problem

Please walk me through on how to solve this:

A sum of $1000 is deposited in an account with an interest rate of r percent compounded monthly. At the end of 5 years, the balance in the account is given by:

$A= 1000(1+r/1200)^{60}$

Find the rate of change of A with respect to r for the following rates:
a. r= 8%
b. r= 10%
c. r= 12%

So far, this is what I've come up with but I don't know if it's correct. Also, should it be $dA/dr$ ?

[Partial solution](https://i.stack.imgur.com/whyrl.jpg)

Answer (score 1):

It's not an implicit differentiation problem. It is asked directly the variation of an explicit function. You did it well except for your equating $A'$ to $1$

$$\frac{\mathrm dA}{\mathrm dr}=1000·60\left(1+\frac{r}{1200}\right)^{59}\frac{\mathrm d}{\mathrm dr}\left(1+\frac{r}{1200}\right)=$$

$$=\frac{1000·60}{1200}\left(1+\frac{r}{1200}\right)^{59}=50\left(1+\frac{r}{1200}\right)^{59}$$

Now, this variation is to be calculated for some values of $r$. e.g.

$$\frac{\mathrm dA}{\mathrm dr}(8)=50\left(1+\frac{8}{1200}\right)^{59}\approx74.00$$

Comment: Oh my bad. But in your last equation, shouldn't it be 50 instead of 5?

Comment: Ok, left one $0$. Fixed. Sometimes problems seem harder that they are. Read the help for formatting formulas. You have a lot of possibities in the interface too.

Comment: May i ask why is it (approx) equal to 40 and not 80? I calculated it using the equation above but I get an answer of 80. Am I missing something?

Comment: http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=50+(1+%2B+8.%2F1200)%5E(59)

Comment: I am not sure now what I put into calculations, but @Moo did them by ours. Thanks and sorry :)

Comment: We can heck the meaning of the the derivative. It is "dolars by percentual point" of increase. It's greater the increase as $r$ grows.